# Table splitting in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an unusual situation regarding DB table splitting; I have a table named 'message' holding info for messages to be sent via email:

```
Message                              Status
--------------------------------     -------------
id | subject | body | status_id      status_id | caption
--------------------------------     ----------------------
1    random    bla    3              1           draft
2    second    hello  3              2           scheduled
15   subj      ok     1              3           archived
```

When message is created, it's status is automatically set to `draft`, it can be `scheduled`, and finally, when sent to at least one contact, it's status is `archived`.

My boss suggests that messages should be split in `three tables` named

> draft,
>
> scheduled and
>
> archived.

In practice, almost everytime you search for `message` in DB for sending `(status is 'draft')`, the table contains large amount of unneeded data (messages with status 'archived'). But, if I split the table, everytime I change the status of a message, I have to insert it to the corresponding table, and `delete` from current `status` table.

Since I haven't heard of such a practice before, I ask for an opinion. Is it valid to `split` the tables? Thanks in advance

Comment: you could look at partitioning https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-key.html

Comment: You should be able to partition based on status

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split the tables for this. For optimized queries you should add more indexes, particulariy you can use index on the status_id column. Also I dont see the point of having the statuses in a separate table. if you need the caption you can use that as status_id, otherwise you can just use a regular integer.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, that creates unnecessary overhead when processing your messages.  Using the status_id to filter your results should provide what you need to find messages in "draft" status.  As long as you have the proper indexes in place on your table, performance shouldn't be an issue.  At some point, depending on volume, you MAY want to truly archive those messages to another table, but that is purely a design consideration.  It depends on whether you need to keep records of those messages for a specified amount of time.

Comment: I agree .. this sounds like what a boss that doesn't program would suggest to a programmer.  It SOUNDS like a good idea, but its way better to keep identical data together and just sort them on an iteger value so you only have to change a number and not move records to and from tables.  Such as 1 = draft, 2 = sent , 3 archive or what not.  Just use a column, and use WHERE statements so you can pull only what you need ..